# Does PayPal support a backup code for two-factor auth?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor

Google and DropBox have backup codes in case you can't get access to one of the devices you have registered. Does PayPal have a backup code?

Comment: Downvoter, please clarify the problem with my question.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I'd guess it's because you're asking for product support, which is borderline off-topic here.

Comment: I have flagged it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes & No. It's not a simple backup code, it's a series of questions to confirm your identity.

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_security-key-faq#breakmyToken

```
**Can I still log in to my PayPal account if I lose or break my key, or if I don’t have my mobile phone with me?**
Yes. During login, we’ll ask you questions to help confirm your identity. When you answer them correctly, you’ll be able to log in.
```

Comment: Yeah, I had to use it once when paypal started sending corrupted SMSes to everyone for several days... While I like 2-factor and use it on many systems, thanks to paypal 1) not being able to secure it properly (we all know security questions are bad, bad, bad and 2) messing up what they have managed, I nolonger feel it is worth it on paypal.